# Change default git push to origin HEAD:refs/for/master

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, gerrit, git-push, gerrithub.io

I'm using VS Code and **Gerrit**.
And anytime I'm trying push anything using the VS code GUI.

I have following error:

> git push origin master:master
> remote: error: branch refs/heads/master:
> remote: Push to refs/for/master to create a review, or get 'Push' rights to update the branch.
> remote: User: user_name
> remote: Contact an administrator to fix the permissions
> remote:
> remote: Processing changes: refs: 1
> remote: Processing changes: refs: 1, done
> To ssh://gerrit.company_name.co.uk:11111/SomeRepo
> ! [remote rejected] master -> master (prohibited by Gerrit: not permitted: update)
> error: failed to push some refs to 'ssh://gerrit.company_name.co.uk:11111/SomeRepo'

However everything works if I do it manually using the following command:

`git push origin HEAD:refs/for/master`

**[Question]:** How can I change
`git push origin master:master`
to
`git push origin HEAD:refs/for/master`?

In the .gitconfig I've tried to add the following options, but it is still not working for me.

````
[remote "origin"]
fetch = +refs/heads/master:refs/remotes/origin/master
push = refs/heads/master:refs/for/master```
````